# Oracle SQL -- Fixing data with "impossible" date ranges

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I am working with a table that, for each ID, has a list of "events", where an event is whether or not the object represented by that ID went "On" or "Off." Items assumingly start as off if they are not in this table. An item can only legally go on if was not on at that point.

Here's an example of what it might look like:

```
Events
ID   Type    Date
1    On      01-MAY-12
1    Off     01-JUN-12
1    On      05-JUN-12
```

Unfortunately, this data is terrible and it is filled with impossibilities. Here is what part of this table actually looks like:

```
Events
ID   Type    Date
1    On      01-MAY-12
1    On      01-MAY-12
1    On      01-JUN-12
1    Off     01-JUL-12
1    Off     01-AUG-12
1    On      05-AUG-12
```

What I want to do is write a query that returns this table without junk data, where impossible rows (that is, rows that turn the item on when it's already on, or off when it's already off) are removed.

I don't care too much about the case of it being 'off' before being turned on for the first time as I don't believe we have any cases of that.

So, said query would return:

```
Events
ID   Type    Date
1    On      01-MAY-12
1    Off     01-JUL-12
1    On      01-AUG-12
```

Any thoughts on how to do this? This logic of "return the first row under condition X" is causing me a lot of difficulty. If I just wanted the first on row or first off row, period, I could just group by and grab a min. But how do I do it in this case?

Comment: I notice that you have some duplicates in `(ID, Date)`, at least at the granularity of the day. In such a case, how do you decide which is older and which is newer? Do they have different hours/minutes/seconds?

Comment: @ruakh I don't really care, but in this case it's because the granularity goes down to seconds, so one really is before the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write this:

```
SELECT id,
       type,
       "date"
  FROM ( SELECT id,
                LAG(type) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "date") AS prev_type,
                type,
                "date"
           FROM events
       )
 WHERE type <> NVL(prev_type, '-')
 ORDER
    BY "date"
;
```

Notes:

- `date` isn't really a valid column name unless you wrap it in double-quotes. I'm guessing that's not really the name of the column?
- You wrote, "I don't care too much about the case of it being 'off' before being turned on for the first time as I don't believe we have any cases of that", so I decided *not* to remove initial `Off`s, but that's actually no harder: just change `NVL(prev_type, '-')` to `NVL(prev_type, 'Off')`.
- I didn't worry about the case that that you have two records with the same `id` and `"date"` and different `type`s, because I had no idea how you wanted that handled. I hope you don't need them to be put in whatever-order-makes-them-possible, because that would be significantly harder.

Comment: This is absolutely incredible and a far better solution than I would have thought possible. I also was not familiar with the lag function. I'll be able to handle the edge cases myself. Thank you.